# Invalid Signature - XCode 4.4, Mac App Store

Tags: xcode, macos, signature, mac-app-store

I keep getting this error when I attempt to upload my app to the MAS.

**Invalid Signature** - the main app bundle MyApp at path MyApp.app is signed but the signature is invalid. Refer to the Code Signing and Application Sandboxing Guide for more information.

I've deleted all the old certs and downloaded new ones directly from xcode 4.4, and nothing works. Help!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, deleting (multiple times) and refreshing the certs AND cleaning the build finally got it to work.